# JAVA - Hidden Class Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, hidden

I am a beginner in selenium and I would like to press a file submission field.
I have already done a whole code to connect to the page, click on the buttons etc. (everything works, my driver is good)

But impossible to click on adding file
I looked on the internet how to do it, I added time, tried to browse the frames, used javascript for the hidden class... I tried all the buttons in the field and it doesn't detect them.

[Add File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBREt.png)

[Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baqjS.png)

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);// 1 minute 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*@id=\"yui_3_17_2_1_1584634673387_348\"]/div[1]/div[1]/a")));`


org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="yui_3_17_2_1_1584634673387_348"]/div[1]/div[1]/a"}
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Prefer to paste images directly inside the questions. Links can be broken in the future.

Comment: Quite possibly Why someone will write the code from image for you to reproduce the problem. add it as code. Also give a read to [mcve] and follow that in you questions all the time to get maximum good answers

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue I observed looking at the code is the incorrect locator in your Explicit Condition element checking line. It can be replaced with below code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='yui_3_17_2_1_1584634673387_348']/div[1]/div[1]/a")));
```

Basic XPath Syntax for reference though it has it's variations:

```
//tagname[@attrbute='value']
```

Additional advice Though I am not sure about the application you are automating, but the ID is likely to be changed. Based on the DOM Structure you have provided in the link above I would say change the locator to something on the lines of:

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@role='button'][@title='Add..']")));
```